# Error while installing perl module using cpanm

Tags: linux, perl, cpan, cpanm

I am using perlbrew and cpanm. Upon doing `cpanm Test::More` I get the following:

```
--> Working on Test::More
Fetching http://10.64.0.7:8002/authors/id/L/LO/LOCAL/Test-Simple-1.001003.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Test-Simple-1.001003 ... OK
Building and testing Test-Simple-1.001003 ... OK
Successfully installed Test-Simple-1.001003 (upgraded from 0.98)
cannot unlink file for /home/hamid/.cpanm/work/1406642140.19670/build.log: Permission denied at /loader/0x1bdc0a8/App/cpanminus/script.pm line 99
cannot restore permissions to 0100644 for /home/hamid/.cpanm/work/1406642140.19670/build.log: Permission denied at /loader/0x1bdc0a8/App/cpanminus/script.pm line 99
cannot remove directory for /home/hamid/.cpanm/work/1406642140.19670: Directory not empty at /loader/0x1bdc0a8/App/cpanminus/script.pm line 99
1 distribution installed
```

Can anybody tell me why I am getting the; `cannot unlink file, cannot restore permissions and cannot remove directory` errors?

Would changing the permissions on `/home/hamid/.cpanm/work` be a wise solution to solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have you performed some commands as root?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably ran `cpanm` as root at some time and changed the permissions in your local directory by doing so. You can fix that through:

```
sudo chown -R hamid:hamid ~/.cpanm
```

then it should work fine again.